# SSI (Apache) not working on brand new Ubuntu 16.04 VPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, vps, ssi

So, I just set up a brand new VPS, installed LAMP, all systems and services working.

I've tried almost everything I could find here on Stack Overflow and other guides, ranging from adding things to Apache's default.conf, to including almost every possible directive in .htaccess known to man (though I hear I technically don't need to use .htaccess, since I have root access?).

I *do* know that .htaccess is working because I can successfully used DirectoryIndex.

Not sure if relevant, I am using PHP 7.0.

If anyone needs more specific information, I can quickly find it. I really want SSI to be working!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally, for some reason I stumbled upon an entirely different SO thread which had the answer.

I never enabled `include`.

SOLUTION: `a2enmod include`.